# CodeIgniter + Google Maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, smarty

One of my model methods returns an array of records that, among other details, contain latitude and longitude details. For example:

```
['user_id'] => 25
['latitude'] => 100
['longitude'] => 100
['name'] => 'John Doe'
```

The array of records is then assigned to a Smarty variable so that the view files can display the information. I also want to display a map with markers (in the example above, to represent where users are).

Google Maps need the latitude and longitude information. I don't want to have to make an Ajax call to grab the latitude/longitude information after the page is rendered -- mainly because I have already pushed that data to the view files via Smarty variable.

I supposed I could use that Smarty variable to create a JS variable on the page where the map needs to be displayed -- but I try to keep mark up and scripts separate.

Suggestion how to address this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo the php latitude longitude vars to an javascript array.

More info on placing the markers on your map with the array you would generate: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

Answer (score 0):

You can put the latitude and longitude in the HTML as attributes and extract them in your JS. This will allow you to keep your JS file separate from your HTML.

That said, I think it'd be easier to just embed a block of JS in your HTML and assign the data to a JS variable directly. It's faster, easy to maintain, and has the same amount of coupling.